# Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532) after using switch case to confirm it is not undefined

Tags: typescript

I used `case "x" in testObject` before `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` occurred at `testObject["x"]`, why is that?

Do I need to write my own type guard for it?

```js
interface TestObject {
  a?: number;
  b?: number;
  c?: number;
  d?: number;
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  z?: number;
}

function foo(testObject: TestObject) {
  switch (true) {
    case "x" in testObject:
      testObject["x"] + 1;
    case "y" in testObject:
      testObject["y"] + 2;
    case "z" in testObject:
      testObject["z"] + 3;
    case "a" in testObject:
      testObject["a"] + 10;
    case "b" in testObject:
      testObject["b"] + 7;
    case "c" in testObject:
      testObject["c"] + 9;
    case "d" in testObject:
      testObject["d"] + 23;
  }
}

foo({ x: 1, y: 2 });
```

P.S. I know the demo code is weird, but I have to check ten cases (based on which key exists in the object to do different actions) in my application.

Answer (score 3):

You check if `"x"` is in your object `testObject`. But that doesn't mean the value of the property cannot be `undefined`. You defined `x` in `TestObject` as optional (`?`).

Your guard would work fine if you checked for the value of `testObject["x"]` to be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) as well. For example:

```
interface TestObject {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
}

function foo(testObject: TestObject) {
  if ("x" in testObject && testObject["x"]) {
    return testObject["x"] + 1; // compiles
  }

  return 0;
}

foo({x: 1, y: 2});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gPICMBWECYyA3gLABQyyAHgPwBcyIArgLa7QDcVNAnkxYcuUXpQC+VKjFYhiwAPYhkMRYoAUkLHkLFm6HQSJgAlGT7JgMZBoBEtO1ZXacx4sgBkn5K90mAbQc7AF1zCmoaZCgIMFYoF0w3PTAgxxDkAGpkAEZxGilIyxi4hOQABnFCmXUNUlpmHIAaZH5mACYJU24gA)

Comment: You say “null” here where you should probably say “undefined”.    An optional property cannot generally be null.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Any alternative if I want to check `if ("x" in testObject && testObject["x"]) || ("y" in testObject && testObject["y"]) || ("z" in testObject && testObject["z"])`? @Behemoth

Comment: Also, I would like to use `case` `switch` since I have many cases to check, I have edited the question, sorry for the confusion. @Behemoth